# Como validar acesso a uma API para apenas o domínio licenciado?

Tags: php, validação, token, licença

Estou procurando ideias originais de como validar o acesso a uma API em php para apenas o domínio que pagou a licença, uma vez que `SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` não é confiável.

Eu criei um chave de ativação em json e encriptei, gerei um método de decrepitação, mais isso não garante que a chave possa ser copiada para múltiplos domínios. Alguém já implementou algo do gênero com uma solução alternativa?

```
  public function GerarKeyToken($tamanho = 8, $maiusculas = true, $numeros true, $simbolos = false){
    // Caracteres de cada tipo
    $lmin = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $lmai = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $num  = '1234567890';
    $simb = '!@#$%*-';
    // Variáveis internas
    $retorno     = '';
    $caracteres  = '';
    // Agrupamos todos os caracteres que poderão ser utilizados
    $caracteres .= $lmin;
    if ($maiusculas) $caracteres .= $lmai;
    if ($numeros) $caracteres .= $num;
    if ($simbolos) $caracteres .= $simb;
    // Calculamos o total de caracteres possíveis
    $len = strlen($caracteres);
    for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
      // Criamos um número aleatório de 1 até $len para pegar um dos caracteres
      $rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
      // Concatenamos um dos caracteres na variável $retorno
      $retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
    }
    return $retorno;
  }

  public function Encrypt($MegaImporterLicenca){
    $key           = hash('sha256', $MegaImporterLicenca->GetKeyToken());
    $iv            = substr(hash('sha256', $MegaImporterLicenca->GetKeyToken()), 0, 16);
    $encrypt_text  = json_encode(array('id'        => $MegaImporterLicenca->GetId(),
                                       'dominio'   => $MegaImporterLicenca->GetDominio(),
                                       'cadastro'  => $MegaImporterLicenca->GetCadastro(),
                                       'expiracao' => $MegaImporterLicenca->GetExpiracao()));
    $output        = openssl_encrypt($encrypt_text, METHOD, $key, 0, $iv);
    $output        = base64_encode($output);
    return $output;
  }

  public function Decrypt($MegaImporter,$hash){
    $key    = hash('sha256', $MegaImporter->GetKeyToken());
    $iv     = substr(hash('sha256', $MegaImporter->GetKeyToken()), 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($hash), METHOD, $key, 0, $iv);
    return $output;
  }
```

Comment: Muito ampla a questão, pois depende de como vai ser consumida a API. Se for consumida só no servidor, pode limitar a quantidade de IPs num determinado tempo. Se for consumida só no browser, o `REFERER` é uma boa. Se é em ambos, precisa limitar a quantidade de consultas para que a pessoa não queira "dividir" a chave (ou cobrar por consulta, ai tanto faz de onde cada um acessa). Seu problema não é limitar o acesso, e sim receber o $ corretamente por isso. Transfira o prejuizo de dividir a chave para o cliente, que o problema se resolve.

Comment: O problema do REFERER é que pode ser falsificado, não é seguro. A api só deve dar acesso aos domínios que compraram a licença.Preciso apenas de idéias alternativas a lógica eu implemento. Obrigado pela correção, erro de digitação.

Comment: Como eu falei, se vai ser consumido no browser, é uma ótima o REFERER. Seu cliente não vai poder passar na casa de cada usuário final para falsificar isso. Jà, se ele acessar pelo servidor dele, ai ele falsifica. Por isso que depende do caso, e por isso que em cada situação tem um jeito de resolver. Só sabendo detalhes.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar um `Header` que dá acesso a somente a alguns dominios...
O `Header` é o `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` e você pode utiliza-lo de acordo com o exemplo abaixo...

```
<?php
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
$allowed_domains = [
    'http://mysite1.com',
    'https://www.mysite2.com',
    'http://www.mysite2.com',
];

if (in_array($origin, $allowed_domains)) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Vitor Braga por sua ideia, mas $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] não é enviado por todos os navegadores e também não é confiável.